# Play Movie Clip in reverse and return to frame 1

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I'm doing a little animation using Actionscript 3.0 but I'm having a few problems (I'm new with AS3) when I want to play a movie clip in reverse and, then, return to frame 1(main).

Here is my code:

```
B6_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickReverse6);

function onClickReverse6(event:MouseEvent):void{
    m6_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playReverse6, false, 0, true);
}

function playReverse6(event:Event):void{
    if(m6_mc.currentFrame == 1){
        if(playMusic){
            playMusic.stop();
        }
        gotoAndStop(1);
    }else{
        m6_mc.prevFrame();
    }
}
```

The error I get is with the line

> "if(m6_mc.currentFrame == 1)" - ERROR #1009: Cannot access a property
>   or method of a null object reference

If I remove the command *gotoAndStop(1)*, no error is presented.

Can anyone, please, help me with my code?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you are calling `gotoAndStop` some other MovieClip (it's actually whatever `this` is in your case). But at this time you are checking the `currentFrame` property fo the `m6_mc`.

I think there might be some error with that. If you switch `this` to frame 1, is there a `m6_mc` instance (if you're not keeping it in a variable)?

Answer (score 0):

I have this code on frame 1, regarding the code presented before:

```
function onClick6(event:MouseEvent):void{
 musicLoader = new URLRequest("music/GABRIEL.mp3");
 music = new Sound();
 music.load(musicLoader);
 playMusic = music.play(0,4);
 gotoAndStop(7);
 m6_mc.gotoAndPlay(1);}
```